# Practical application of Gauss-Lucas theorem

Tags: geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb C$ pairwise distinct be the affix of
points $A,
B$ and $C$.
Let $P(x)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)(x-z_3)$.
Let $z_4$ and $z_5$ be the roots of $P'$ (with the possibilty that
$z_4=z_5$), and denote by $D$ and $E$ the corresponding points in the plane.

According to Gauss-Lucas theorem we know that $D$ and $E$ are in
convex hull of 
triangle $ABC$.

I'd like to express $D$ as $D= \alpha A +\beta B +(1-\alpha -\beta)C$
with $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$ and $\alpha +\beta \leq 1$, and similar
for $E$.

I could obtain so far $z_{4,5} = \frac{z_1+z_2+z_3}{3} \pm
\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(z_1+z_2+z_3)^2 -3(z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_1z_3)}$.

Any idea?

Comment: The [proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) gives an explicit representation.

Comment: @Steven, I know that, thank you, but with that proof you end up with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depending on $D$ or $z_4$. I should probably have been more explicit early on but I'd like to avoid that dependency.

Comment: Why not plug the formula you have for $z_4$ (or $z_5$) as $z$ into RHS of $$\alpha : \beta : 1-\alpha-\beta = \frac{1}{|z - z_1|^2} : \frac{1}{|z - z_2|^2} : \frac{1}{|z - z_3|^2}$$
It is messy, but the end result doesn't depend on $z_4$ (or $z_5$) explicitly.

Comment: achille, what is $z$? Isn't it $z_4$?

Comment: If you want $\alpha, \beta$ for $D$, then substitute $z$ by$z_4$. If you want the corr. numbers for $E$, then substitute $z$ by $z_5$ instead.

Comment: I thought so, so your earlier statement "the end result doesn't depend on $z_4$ (or $z_5$) explicitly", falls appart. As a said in my comment before your first one, "I'd like to avoid that dependency"